# How to frame unordered arguments in docopt?

Tags: go, docopt

I'm trying to frame a docopt usage which accepts set of options.

```
Naval Fate.

Usage:
  naval_fate.py ship
  [-b <b_command>]
  [-e <e_command>]
```

Runnable example: 
http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Naval+Fate.%0D%0A%0D%0AUsage%3A%0D%0A++naval_fate.py+ship%0D%0A++%5B-b+%3Cb_command%3E%5D%0D%0A++%5B-e+%3Ce_command%3E%5D&argv=ship+-e+c+

If I use this, it works fine:

`ship -b barg -e earg`

The output is:

```
{
  "-b": true, 
  "-e": true, 
  "<b_command>": "barg", 
  "<e_command>": "earg", 
  "ship": true
}
```

But if use this, it still gives the same values to the respective arguments:

```
ship -e earg -b barg
```

Output:

```
{
  "-b": true, 
  "-e": true, 
  "<b_command>": "earg", 
  "<e_command>": "barg", 
  "ship": true
}
```

Note that I passed earg to -e but it is assigned to b_command in the output.

I saw the same behavior with golang's `docopt-go` package. Is my usage string wrong? If so, how should I frame the docopt usage string such that it assigns the correct values correct arguments and honors the specified arguments?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> naval_fate.py ship
> [-b <b_command>]
> [-e <e_command>]
> ```

The interpretation of the docopt you wrote is as follows:

- The subcommand `ship`,
- Followed by zero or more of the following in any order:

  - The boolean flag `-b`,
  - A positional argument `<b_command>`,
  - The boolean flag `-e`,
  - A positional argument `<e_command>`.

So all of the following would be considered legal input commands:

```
naval_fate.py ship -e
naval_fate.py ship BB -e
naval_fate.py ship -eb
naval_fate.py ship BB EE
```

The correct way to express flags like `-b <b_command>` and `-e <e_command>` is through a section called `Options`.

```
Naval Fate.

Usage:
  naval_fate.py ship [options]

Options:
  -b <b_command>   Description of -b
  -e <e_command>   Description of -e
```

Comment: But is it possible to make the options repeatable if we specify them in Options section? That is, I need to be able to "ship -b firstb -b secondb -e firste -e seconde. Thank you.

Comment: I believe it is not. This is being tracked in [docopt/docopt#275](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/275).